# Find table total rows

Tags: sapui5

I need table bound data total rows number for further loop. How can we get table rows count?

I'm getting `undefined` on button press:

```
var tab= this.getView().byId("idOrderDetailTable");
var obj = tab.getBindingContext("ProductCollection");
console.log(" >> ",obj );
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Live Update the Number of Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48308896/live-update-the-number-of-items)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var tab= this.getView().byId("idOrderDetailTable");
//get binding path of table items 
var bindingPath = tab.getBinding("items").sPath;
//get data model of table
var model = tab.getModel();
//get bind data
var data = model.getProperty(bindingPath);
//get total rows number
var rowCount = data.length;
console.log(" >> ",rowCount );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var tab= this.getView().byId("idOrderDetailTable");
var length = tab.getItems().length
```

This should be a simpler way.

Answer (score -1):

If you use sap.ui.table.Table and didn't bind Model:

```
var length = oTable._iBindingLength;
```

Comment: Please avoid relying on private members (`._`) from the framework code. This **will** break the application in newer framework releases. Use only what is visible in the public API reference.