# Live Update the Number of Items

Tags: sapui5

I have a requirement where I need to live update the number of list items to Page's sub-header. I want use `sap.ui.base.EventProvider`, aggregation binding, or expression binding. Please walk me through as I have never used it before.

If I delete a list item, the number of list item should live update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Client-side Models

If a **client-side** model such as `JSONModel` is used (i.e. assuming all the data are already available on the client) and if the target collection is an **array**, a simple expression binding is sufficient:

```
title="{= ${myJSONModel>/myProducts}.length}"
```

- **Sample 1 (ClientModel):** [Updating count after deleting items from `sap.m.Table`](https://embed.plnkr.co/NGnnqI/?show=view%2FHome.view.xml,controller%2FHome.controller.js,preview&sidebar=tree&autoCloseSidebar=true)
- **Sample 2 (ClientModel):** [Updating count after filtering `sap.ui.table.Table`](https://embed.plnkr.co/IvI5gWXFaeo2yxiw?show=view%2FHome.view.xml,controller%2FHome.controller.js,preview&sidebar=tree&autoCloseSidebar=true)

As you can see in the above samples, when the number of items changes, the framework notifies the [Expression Binding](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/daf6852a04b44d118963968a1239d2c0) which eventually updates the property value automatically.

## Server-side Models (e.g. OData)

### OData V2

#### Using `updateFinished` event from `sap.m.ListBase`[<sup>api</sup>](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.ListBase/events/updateFinished)

Especially if the growing feature is enabled, this event comes in handy to get always the new count value which the framework assigns to the event parameter `total`.

> [The parameter `total`] can be used if the `growing` property is set to `true`.

- **Sample 3 (v2.ODataModel)**: [Updating count after filtering `sap.m.ListBase`](https://embed.plnkr.co/pVsUr5?show=view/Home.view.xml,controller/Home.controller.js,preview&sidebar=tree&autoCloseSidebar=true)

```xml
<List
  growing="true"
  items="{/Products}"
  updateFinished=".onUpdateFinished"
>
```

```js
onUpdateFinished: function(event) {
  const reason = event.getParameter("reason"); // "Filter", "Sort", "Refresh", "Growing", ..
  const count = event.getParameter("total"); // Do something with this $count value
  // ...
},
```

The `updateFinished` event is fired after items binding is updated and processed by the control. The event parameter `"total"` provides the value of `$count` that has been requested according to the operation such as filtering, sorting, etc..

#### Using `change` event from `sap.ui.model.Binding`[<sup>api</sup>](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.Binding/events/change)

This event can be applied to **any** bindings which comes in handy especially if the control doesn't support the `updateFinished` event.

```xml
someAggregation="{
  path: '/Products',
  events: {
    change: '.onChange'
  }
}"
```

```js
onChange: function(event) {
  const reason = event.getParameter("reason"); // See: sap.ui.model.ChangeReason
  const count = event.getSource().getLength();
  // ...
},
```

- `event.getSource()` returns the corresponding (List)Binding object which has the result of `$count` (or `$inlinecount`) [stored internally](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/d8f7d3e26ec9e903be57a2831211f8e151840a5d/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/model/odata/v2/ODataListBinding.js#L739-L740). We can get that count result by calling the [public API **`getLength()`**](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataListBinding#methods/getLength).
- One downside is that there is **no `"growing"` reason included** in [`sap.ui.model.ChangeReason`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.model.ChangeReason). But if the control can grow, it's probably derived from the ListBase anyway which supports the `updateFinished` event.

#### Manual trigger (Only in V2)

If there is no list binding at all but the count value is still required, we can always send a request manually to get the count value. For this, append the system query `$count` to the path in the read method:

```js
myV2ODataModel.read("/Products/$count", {
  filters: [/*...*/],
  success: function(data) {
    const count = +data; // "+" parses the string to number.
    // ...
  }.bind(this),
})
```

### OData V4

Please, take a look at the documentation topic *[Binding Collection Inline Count](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/77d2310b637b490495d78b393ed6aa64)*.

Answer (score -2):

I will guess that "MyListModel" is your model name and inside it you have something like this:

```
[
  {objectName: "object1"},
  {objectName: "object2"},
  {objectName: "object3"}
]
```

Then try:

```
<Page title="{= ${myListModel>/}.length}">
```