# How to bind count value to a single property?

Tags: odata, sapui5

I am currently working on single Tiles and want to add some count values from the Northwind OData service. The app contains just one view and one controller.

#### View

```xml
<mvc:View
  controllerName="customtileapp.controller.CustomTile1"
  xmlns="sap.m"
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
>
  <GenericTile
    class="sapUiTinyMarginBegin sapUiTinyMarginTop tileLayout"
    header="Country-Specific Profit Margin"
    subheader="Expenses" press="press"
  >
    <TileContent
      unit="EUR"
      footer="Current Quarter"
    >
      <NumericContent
        scale="M"
        value="{
          path: '/Customers',
          formatter: '.formatTile'
        }"
        valueColor="Error"
        indicator="Up"
        formatterValue="true"
      />
    </TileContent>
  </GenericTile>
</mvc:View>
```

#### Controller

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
  "sap/m/MessageToast",
  "sap/ui/model/odata/v2/ODataModel"
], function (Controller, MessageToast, ODataModel){
  "use strict";

  return Controller.extend("customtileapp.controller.CustomTile1", {
    onInit: function() {
      this.oView = this.getView();
      this.oModel = new ODataModel("/northwind/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc");
      this.oView.setModel(this.oModel);
    },

    formatTile: function() {
      var counter;
      this.oModel.read("/Customers/$count", {
        async : true,
        success : function(oData, response) {
          counter = response.body;
          MessageToast.show(counter);
        }
      });
      return counter;
    }
  });
});
```

The MessageToast inside the formatter Function works fine and shows the correct number of customers (`"91"`). But the number I want to show on the tile always shows `"0"`.

[image: Tile]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to the earlier response from Nandan, I usually use a standalone method to get the value for a tile.

```html
        getTileValue: function () {
            var oTileValue = this.myView.byId('tileValue');
            this.getModel().read('/Dealers/$count', {
                success: $.proxy(function (oEvent, oResponse) {
                    var count = Number(oResponse.body);
                    oTileValue.setValue(count);
                }, this)
            });
        },
```

I like this because I can setup a timer to regularly update the counter.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very different approach to what you are trying to achieve. However here is some information I could derive to get this:

[image]

1. Why value returned by formatter is not showing up in binding ? 
   Ans : This will not show up! 
   Why : **Binding** at view **does not wait for the formatter** function **to return** the value. The read request performed in formatter is '**async**' by default.
   However, even if it had to work synchronously, you could try something like this :

   formatTile: function() {
       var counter;
           this.oModel.read("/Customers/$count", {async : true,
                                   success : function(oData, response) {
                                       counter = response.body;
   return counter;

   }}); 
   }

But this won't work as well as read may take a while and the binding would not wait.

1. Updating the $count is typically used in List and Table headers. Where it works as follows (which I also applied as a workaround)

**There shall be an event trigger**(onUpdateFinishedMaster in my example) in order to get the count of Customers and then the value in NumericContent can be updated.

Controller:

```js
sap.ui.define(['sap/m/MessageToast', 'sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller'],
 function(MessageToast, Controller) {
  "use strict";

  return Controller.extend("tilesGenericTIles.controller.View1", {
   onInit: function() {
    this.oView = this.getView();
    this.oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel("/destinations/northwind/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/", true);
    this.oView.setModel(this.oModel);
   },
   formatTile: function(sCount) {
    
    var counter;
    this.oModel.read("/Customers/$count", {
     async: true,
     success: function(oData, response) {
      
      counter = response.body;
      return counter;
      MessageToast.show(sCount);
     }
    });
    
    return 'test' ;

   },
   onUpdateFinishedMaster: function(oEvent){
    // 
    var count,
    oTable = oEvent.getSource();
    var iTotalItems = oEvent.getParameter("total");
    
    this.getView().byId("idNumericContent").setValue(iTotalItems);
   }

  });
 });

View:
```

```html
<mvc:View controllerName="tilesGenericTIles.controller.View1"  xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
 displayBlock="true" xmlns="sap.m">
 <App>
  <pages>
   <Page title="{i18n>title}">
    <content>
     <l:VerticalLayout>
      <GenericTile class="sapUiTinyMarginBegin sapUiTinyMarginTop tileLayout" header="Country-Specific Profit Margin" subheader="Expenses"
       press="press">
       <TileContent unit="EUR" footer="Current Quarter">
        <NumericContent scale="MM" value="{path: 'Customers', formatter: '.formatTile'}" valueColor="Error" indicator="Up" id="idNumericContent"/>
       </TileContent>
      </GenericTile>
      <Table id="idMasterTable" width="auto" items="{ path: '/Customers'}" noDataText="{i18n>masterTableNoDataText}"
       busyIndicatorDelay="{worklistView>/tableBusyDelay}" growing="true" growingScrollToLoad="true" updateFinished="onUpdateFinishedMaster"
       mode="SingleSelectLeft" inset="false" selectionChange="onMasterTableSelectionChange">
       <columns>
        <Column vAlign="Middle" id="idColumnAppGrp">
         <header>
          <Text text="{Customer Name}"/>
         </header>
        </Column>
        <Column vAlign="Middle" id="idColumnAppGrp1">
         <header>
          <Text text="{Customer Name}"/>
         </header>
        </Column>
       </columns>
        <items>
         <ColumnListItem type="Navigation" press="handleMasterPress" tooltip="{i18n>masterColumnItemTooltip}">
          <cells>
           <ObjectIdentifier title="{ContactName}"/>
           <ObjectIdentifier title="{ContactName}"/>
          </cells>
         </ColumnListItem>
        </items>
       </Table>
      </l:VerticalLayout>
     </content>
    </Page>
   </pages>
  </App>
 </mvc:View>
```

[image: Update Count on button press]

1. Add a button beside the generic tile:

```html
      <l:HorizontalLayout>
      <GenericTile class="sapUiTinyMarginBegin sapUiTinyMarginTop tileLayout" header="Country-Specific Profit Margin" subheader="Expenses"
       press="press">
       <TileContent unit="EUR" footer="Current Quarter">
        <NumericContent scale="MM" value="{path: 'Customers', formatter: '.formatTile'}" valueColor="Error" indicator="Up" id="idNumericContent"/>
       </TileContent>
      </GenericTile>
      <Button text="updateCount" press="updateCount" />
      </l:HorizontalLayout>
```

2. Update count of the tile on press event.

```js
   updateCount: function(oEvent){
     
    var counter;
    this.oModel.read("/Customers/$count", {
     async: true,
     success: function(oData, response) {
      
      counter = response.body;
      this.getView().byId("idNumericContent").setValue(counter);
     }.bind(this)
    });
```

Additionally, the function "updateCounter" can also be called periodically with a timer.

Kindly let me know if this helps.

Comment: Dear Nanda, 
thanks a lot! It works now :-) So, am I right that without the table I could not get the counter to the tile? Because I want to show the Tile in a Firoi Launchpad (via Portal) and do not really need to show the table (just need the tile :))

Comment: @Timur As Nandan mentioned, the main issue is that the `formatTile` returns `undefined` since the GET request, triggered by the `read` method, is sent asynchronously. The formatter doesn't wait until the client receives the count value. You can always update the count *manually* without a table (ListBinding).

Comment: @Timur , you should update the count manually on any event as I've mentioned above . thanks Boghyon for adding more clarification on this .

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann thanks for your help! But how can I do it without any table or list, I don't really get it :(

Comment: Here is what I did as an example to update the count manually:
fire the press event of a button and execute the code of your formatter. 
Check updated answer for this.

Comment: Hi Nandan, thanks a lot! It now works fine :) I used the code from Graham above. But your feature is very cool. I will also use it in my Application

Answer (score 0):

If you were working with a JSON model (not OData) you could solve this through expression binding right within your XML view.
No need for any fancy controller math:

```
  <NumericContent
    ...
    value="{= ${/Customers}.length }"
    ...
  />
```

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48331240/430742) for all your options to count records in different SAPUI5 data models (JSON, OData v2, OData v4).