# How to get the correct row count?

Tags: sapui5

ShowRowCount of SmartTable only shows the correct row count when scrolling to the last entry of table.
If the row count is smaller then 100 the result is correct.
If the row count is bigger then 100, for example 304, the inital result is 100. Now, if i scroll to the bottem and trigger growingScrollToLoad the result is 200. I have to scroll two times more to the bottem and trigger growingScrollToLoad to see the correct result 304.

```
<smartTable:SmartTable id="smartResult" entitySet="someSet" tableType="ResponsiveTable" useExportToExcel="false"
                                useVariantManagement="false" useTablePersonalisation="true" header="Result" showRowCount="true"
                                persistencyKey="SmartTableAnalytical_Explored" enableAutoBinding="false" class="sapUiResponsiveContentPadding"
                                initiallyVisibleFields="Some Field Names"
                                ignoredFields="Some other Field Names"
                                requestAtLeastFields="InternalID">

    <Table id="tableResult" noDataText="{i18n>noData}" growingThreshold="50" mode="Single" sticky="ColumnHeaders" growing="true" growingScrollToLoad="true">
```

Has anybody some idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Live Update the Number of Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48308896/live-update-the-number-of-items)

Answer (score 0):

oData protocol already transfer this information. oData make new async get request for getting total count to backend system for getting this information. Example total count request below.

https://services.odata.org/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Orders/$count

Comment: i can not open the link you posted.

Comment: Given link only return order count as 830. I give this URL for sample.You can check your application network activity for similar request.