# How can I get the count of filtered OData results?

Tags: odata, sapui5

I am attempting to get the count of filtered OData results in a Fiori SAPUI5 application. I am able to get the **correct** count using both `$count` and `$inlinecount` in Postman using the following:
`MyEntitySet/$count?$filter=Id eq '9'`
and
`MyEntitySet?$filter=Id eq '9'&$inlinecount=allpages&$format=json`.

However, when I try to use these query parameters in my UI5 code, I don't get the result I want.

```js
myV2ODataModel.read("/MyEntitySet/$count?$filter=Id eq '9'", {/*...*/});
```

gives me the count of the unfiltered results, while

```js
myV2ODataModel.read("/MyEntitySet?$filter=Id eq '9'&$inlinecount=allpages", {/*...*/});
```

gives me all the records, and I am unable to access the inline count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the documented API reference for `myV2ODataModel.read`: https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel#methods/read

So it should be:

```js
// Filter required from "sap/ui/model/Filter"
myV2ODataModel.read("/MyEntitySet/$count", {
  // ...,
  filters: [
    new Filter(/*...*/), 
  ],
});
```

- API reference for `sap/ui/model/Filter`: https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.model.Filter
- [Live Update the Number of Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48308896/live-update-the-number-of-items)